# While processing add class disabled to the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new in frontend.
I need to disable the button while the user clicks on it while waiting for the processing of the update is over.

I add this code in a function that is called while clicking the button. is this a good approach to disable it?

```
 let updateCallback = function() {
        $('.update-btn').addClass('disabled');
        $('.update-btn').attr('disabled', true);
            save(this);

    };
```

Comment: Looks fine. Is there something about it that doesn't work right for you? No need for the `addClass`

Comment: You don't need `$('.update-btn').addClass('disabled');` unless you really have such a CSS class in the stylesheets.

Comment: Do you have multiple update buttons? This will change them all, not just the one you clicked on.

Comment: @Kinglish, all works fine I just interesing

Comment: @Barmar. I have only one btn

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This itself is enough
`$('.update-btn').attr('disabled', true);`